# reintialize files for a new git repo

Tags: ios, git, github, repository

i deleted a git repo and was hoping to add the same files into my username.github.io repo to host the files in the other repo. i added a username.github.io repo and went back to the folder of the old repo and did the whole git init/add/commit/push origin 'https://ofnewgitrepo.com' only to be told the new repo doesn't exist. now git status is giving me a fatal error saying the old repo doesn't exist! i'm at a loss for what to do. git seems to think it should be looking for the deleted repo within the file folder i'm trying to re-init.

Comment: What `git remote -v` returns?

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem by directing git to the new repo by using

```
git push git@github.com/username/username.github.io.git
```

that did the trick in pointing to the new repo

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @teriiehina He is the OP (blue box around profile area). And this is an answer, he solved his own question.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to change the default origin url, you can type:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com/username/username.github.io.git
```